# Sqlite Error "No Such Table" WHILE COPYING

Tags: sqlite

I am getting error while creating new table by copying table.

```
String countQuery ="CREATE TABLE "+  TABLE_CONTACTSDUMMY +" AS SELECT * FROM "+DATABASE_NAME +"."+ TABLE_CONTACTS +"";
```

> Error :No such table DATABASE_NAME.TABLE_CONTACTS

Comment: what language do you use, does that database and table exist? is it the right database and table name? can you show us the rest of the code (minimum example)? please use correct formatting; code formatted as code, error message as block-quote; read the (help ->)

Comment: YES,Database and table exist.If i remove DATABASE_NAME from query it runs

Comment: String countQuery ="CREATE TABLE "+  TABLE_CONTACTSDUMMY +" AS SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_CONTACTS +"";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

Comment: do not add the code in a comment, but edit your question, and format it as code (read the help)

Comment: I think you need to use `DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName` ;).